# /WEB-INF/web.xml showing MySQL credentials?

Tags: databases, mysql, xml, credentials

I found the file `/WEB-INF/web.xml` on a domain I'm associated with. The XML file contains:

```
<database>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/mysql</jndi-name>
    <driver> 
        <type>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource</type> 
        <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/[domainWasHere]</url>
        <user>[userWasHere]</user>
        <password>[passWasHere]</password>
    </driver>
</database>
```

Could this be vital information in the wrong hands?

Answer (score 1):

*Could* it?  Yes.

*Is* it?  That's less certain.  If your MySQL server is configured properly, it isn't accessible from the Internet at large, and the credentials are useless to anyone who doesn't have the ability to run code on the server.

Of course, this assumes that the username and password are unique to the server.